# How do you use number_to_phone in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, form-for, number-formatting

I am storing phone number in database as "1234567890".

How do can you use number_to_phone to display the number nicely in a form as "(123) 456-7890"?

I tried the following but it showed just the numbers.

`<%= f.text_field number_to_phone(:phone_number) %>`

Thanks.

Comment: If you use the helper in your form, it will mess the data

Comment: just save the number the way it is and use helpers to format it.. like the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create a simple helper like this in your application helper

```
  def format_phone(phone, mobile=false)
    return phone if format.blank?
    groupings = format.scan(/d+/).map { |g| g.length }
    groupings = [3, 3, 4] unless groupings.length == 3
    ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_phone(
      phone,
      :area_code => format.index('(') ? true : false,
      :groupings => groupings,
      :delimiter => format.reverse.match(/[^d]/).to_s
    )
  end
```

then in your view do

```
<%= format_phone(phone_number)%>
```