# Telephone formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and I am trying to figure out how to use the example at http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_phone to format a phone number in my code below.  Trying to figure out how and where I call number_to_phone(number, options = {}) public

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <%= f.text_field :phone, class: 'form-control', autofocus: true, placeholder: 'xxx-xxx-xxxx' %>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should hand in the phone number, or an object that contains the phone number through an instance variable `@your_variable` from your controller to your view.  Let's assume that the instance you are handing in, has an attribute phone_number.

In the view file, you should do something like this:

```
 <%= form_for @person do |f| %>
   <%= f.telephone_field(:phone, :value => @your_variable.phone_number ) %> 

   <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

If you want to have an HTML input field, you should use the appropriate form helpers in your view, e.g.:  telephone_field

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Comment: As I mentioned in my original question I could not figure out how to use it in the example at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must know that `number_to_phone` **method doesn't return an HTML input field**. It returns a `String`. Thus what can be formatted with that method is telephones already saved.

Following code will show a saved telephone formatted inside an input text field.

```
<%= f.text_field :phone, class: 'form-control', autofocus: true, placeholder: 'xxx-xxx-xxxx', value: number_to_phone(@my_variable.telephone, area_code: true, extension: 555) %>
```

If you're looking for some way of masking an input field dynamically (as user types in text), you'll want to use a jQuery library such as [maskedInput](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: Your example did not work.       Error message: /home/ubuntu/workspace/agss/app/views/appointments/_form.html.erb:55: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting => ...a_code: true, extension: 555) );@output_buffer.safe_append=' ... ^ /home/ubuntu/workspace/agss/app/views/appointments/_form.html.erb:392: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' '.freeze; end ^ /home/ubuntu/workspace/agss/app/views/appointments/_form.html.erb:404: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')' /home/ubuntu/workspace/agss/app/views/appointments/_form.html.erb:4

Comment: Wow.. I forgot to set the key "value". Now it is going to work! Please choose my answer if it works for you. @Nuanes

Comment: Your line of text is not saving the phone variable to the database, which is the first line below.  The second line, my original line of code does save it to the database.                                                                                                                                       <%= f.text_field :phone, class: 'form-control', autofocus: true, placeholder: 'xxx-xxx-xxxx', value: number_to_phone(@appointment.phone, area_code: true) %>
            <%= f.text_field :phone, class: 'form-control', autofocus: true, placeholder: 'xxx-xxx-xxxx' %>

Comment: What is the error being thrown? Not saving into database doesn't help a lot

Answer (score 0):

You would use it in show.html.erb

```
<%= number_to_phone(@contact.phone) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use number_to_phone(number, options = {}) in a rails helper or view

Here is an example of a helper used to format the phone
[How do you use number_to_phone in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726316/how-do-you-use-number-to-phone-in-rails-3)